# How to get the attribute_value of a page_object element?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver, pageobjects, page-object-gem

Imagine i have a image like:

```
the_image = @browser.image(:id, 'image01')
```

The way to get the value of its class could be:

```
image_status = the_image.attribute_value('class')
```

Ok. I'm using page_object gem and lets suppose i have the image as element, like:

```
image(:the_image, :id => 'image01')
```

To get the attribute_value i can use:

```
image_status = the_image_element.attribute_value('class')
```

...but i get a DEPRECATION WARNING:

```
*** DEPRECATION WARNING
*** You are calling a method named attribute_value at page.rb:68:in `get_status'.
*** This method does not exist in page-object so it is being passed to the driver.
*** This feature will be removed in the near future.
```

How can i get the `class` value using the page_object element? Sure the answer is easy but i didn't found it. Can you please tell me the way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error is not shown in context of your page object class. Maybe you can add more to the question?

Comment: Hi Dave! There were no error, just and only the Warning. In fact, the method works correctly. The problem is that i didn't know how get the attribute value using page object natively. Justin Ko gives me the answer with: `yourelement_element.attribute('attribute_type')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the latest versions of Page-Object and Watir (v2.2.1 and v6.7.3 respectively), the `attribute_value` will no longer give a deprecation warning. Both `#attribute` and `#attribute_value` are supported.

For older version of Page-Object, you need to use the `#attribute` method:

```
image_status = the_image_element.attribute('class')
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. I googled and search on the Cheezy book and didn't find anything. Also looked on the Cheezy Rubydoc info but it seems i didn't search correctly... I'll triple check next time; thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yout link is unfirtunately broken

Comment: Thanks @SSchneid. I have removed the link. The method is no longer directly defined in the Page-Object gem. It is now being delegated to the underlying `Watir::Element`.